# MYSQL SELECT statement returns null when called inside a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures

Hi I am trying to create a simple procedure with a select statement inside it :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testProcedure(OUT login_id VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    SELECT LOGIN_ID INTO login_id FROM USER_REG_MST WHERE USER_MOBILE_NO = 123;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

The select satatement when called out side the proedure independently returns a value, but when the select is called inside a stored procedure it returns a null.

```
SELECT LOGIN_ID INTO login_id FROM mystrodb.USER_REG_MST WHERE USER_MOBILE_NO = 123;
```

Gives me a value.
But,

```
CALL testProcedure(@out);

SELECT @out;
```

returns a NULL.

Note: the columns is of type VARCHAR(30) (additional info)

Comment: Works fine for me. BTW the 2 queries aren't the same.

Comment: I need to make one of two changes to make it work: either change the name of the procedure variable to be something other than login_id, or explicitly put the table name before the field name in the select.

Comment: Thank you koen, this works. Looks like LOGIN_ID is conflicting.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that for MySQL `LOGIN_ID` and `login_id` are the same variable, so it's not recommended to name parameters and variables as the name of their objects or entities (tables, columns, etc.) of your database, see [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

A couple of options: 1) Change the name of the output parameter of the stored procedure. 2) Include a qualifier to `LOGIN_ID` column, see [9.2.1 Identifier Qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

```sql
...
SELECT `USER_REG_MST`.`LOGIN_ID` INTO `login_id` ...
...
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b660c09da38ddbdd8aeccdfda88441d).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `OUT` parameter and make sure to distinguish between column name vs parameter name:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testProcedure(OUT login_id VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    SET login_id = (SELECT u.LOGIN_ID 
                    FROM USER_REG_MST u WHERE USER_MOBILE_NO = 123);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=10a834c6eb4f696b5f7cf2b36bdd4715)**